# Permission denied despite appropriate permissions using PHP

Tags: php, apache, file, permissions

I'm trying to read a file in PHP and I'm getting a permission denied error although everybody has read access to the file.

**The PHP code:**

```
$config=file_get_contents('/opt/jenkins/home/config.xml');
```

**The error:**

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/opt/jenkins/home/config.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in [...]
```

**The filesystem permission:**

There is a symlink pointing `/opt/jenkins/home/` to `/var/lib/jenkins` and everybody has read permission on the symlink, actual folder, and file.

```
$ ls -lh /opt/jenkins/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sysadmin sysadmin   16 2011-08-04 08:12 home -> /var/lib/jenkins

$ ls -lh /var/lib/ | grep jenkins
drwxr-xr-- 6 jenkins adm     4.0K 2011-08-04 10:04 jenkins

$ ls -lh /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jenkins adm 3.9K 2011-08-04 10:05 /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
```

**Apache configuration**

Configured to folllow symlinks (`Options All`). Adding a `Directory` directive for `/var/lib/jenkins/` makes no difference.

```
<Directory /opt/jenkins/home/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
</Directory>
```

**Additional info**

Whether I use the path through the symlink (`"/opt/jenkins/home/config.xml"`) or the real path (`"/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml"`) I have the same problem.

```
apache2 version=2.2.14-5ubuntu8.4
php version=5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
```

**Any idea as to why I'm getting the error?**

Comment: [`is_writable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) return `FALSE`?

Comment: is apache configured to follow symlinks? afaik there's a SymLink option

Comment: thanks for the comments but please read the question more carefully (I want to read the file, and yes, apache follows is configured to follow the symlinks).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your directory needs `execute` permission for this to work. It does not seem to have world execute, and since `jenkins` is probably not the apache user, and the apache user is not in the `adm` group, it wouldn't work:

```
$ ls -lh /var/lib/ | grep jenkins
drwxr-xr-- 6 jenkins adm     4.0K 2011-08-04 10:04 jenkins
```

Per example:

```
netcoder@netcoder:~$ mkdir foo
netcoder@netcoder:~$ echo hello > foo/bar
netcoder@netcoder:~$ chmod 777 foo/bar
netcoder@netcoder:~$ ls -lsah foo/bar 
4.0K -rwxrwxrwx 1 netcoder netcoder 6 2011-08-04 08:22 foo/bar
netcoder@netcoder:~$ chmod 444 foo/
netcoder@netcoder:~$ ls -lsah | grep foo
4.0K dr--r--r--  2 netcoder netcoder 4.0K 2011-08-04 08:22 foo
netcoder@netcoder:~$ cat foo/bar 
cat: foo/bar: Permission denied
```

Even though `foo/bar` has `0777` permission, if the directory does not have the execute permission, reading its contents is denied.

You'll need the permission to be set for both the target directory and the symbolic link.

Comment: So he need to set the execute right on the real dir, or on the symlink ?

Comment: It **must** be set on both, or on the one he uses in his `file_get_contents()` ?

Comment: `/opt/jenkins/home/` is the symbolic link, it must have execute permission. `/var/lib/jenkins/` is the symbolic link target, it also must have execute permission. Since he's reading `/opt/jenkins/home/config.xml` (it's in the `/opt/jenkins/home/` directory), both the target and the symlink requires execute permission. If he was reading directly from `/var/lib/jenkins/`, he wouldn't need execute permission on the symlink, obviously.

Comment: I had to set permissions on the whole directory tree *containing* the target file for it to work.

Answer (score 8):

You need the execute bit set on all directories in the hierarchy up to that file.

```
chmod o+x /var/lib/jenkins
```

should do the trick.

(Note: `ls -lhd /var/lib/jenkins` is a bit better than `ls -lh ...|grep jenkins`)

Answer (score 5):

Lots of modern boxes (digital ocean, rackspace etc) ship with SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux) for RedHat compatible OSs (like CentOS). This throws another wrench into the works which you need to keep in mind. You can have your permissions *perfectly* set and it will still say permission denied. You need to define a writable context for SELinux:

`sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite -R`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your apache user is not allowed to read or access the web files

1. Check what user is apache running as:

   > ```
   > $ ps aux | grep [a]pache
   > root     40283  0.0  0.2 472548 21116 ?        Ss   14:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
   > www-data 40287  0.0  0.1 472760  8800 ?        S    14:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
   > www-data 40288  0.0  0.1 472760  8540 ?        S    14:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
   > www-data 40289  0.0  0.1 472776  8540 ?        S    14:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
   > ```
2. Check the path ownership of your web files:

   > ```
   > $ namei -mol /home/john/app2/
   > f: /home/john/app2/
   > drwxr-xr-x root root  /
   > drwxr-xr-x root root  home
   > drwx------ john john  john         # <== Ahaa, no access for apache user!
   > drwxr-xr-x john john  john app2
   > ```
3. Adjust permissions accordingly:

Well in this step I will **leave it up to you**, you can either **(a)** **the make apache user 'john' in this example**. Or you could **(b)** **move the web folder to a place outside** home. Where the execute access can be given to the group or to even others without breaking security good practices.

a. Make apache user john (ONLY FOR DEV SITES or if you know what you are doing)

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/envars 
# replace 
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data 
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
# with
export APACHE_RUN_USER=john 
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=john
```

b. Move that folder out of home... what is it doing there anyways?

```
sudo mv /home/john/app2 /var/www/
```

Remember to change the site to match this directory and to restart the apache server.

Here are some references:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FileSystemPermissions