# PHP can't read file with read permissions

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, permissions, filesystems

I have a file with these permissions (0644)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root
```

So from my understanding this file should be readable by anyone.

Now I have this code:

```
file_get_contents('/path/to/file');
```

And it is giving me this

> Warning: file_get_contents(...): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...

What am I missing?

I'm running it from a web server under `www-data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible causes with solutions:

### Reading permissions are required for folders in the file path

Solution: Configure the correct permission rights for the whole folder hierarchy. Also see [this remark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376114/4725998) on PHP safe mode.

### Execution permissions are required for reading the file

It's strange, but [this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941282/php-permission-denied-despite-appropriate-permissions).

Solution: Configure execution rights for file and folders.

### [Access control lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376048/fopen-permission-denied-on-a-file-with-777-permissions) for the server are not configured

Solution: Configure them properly.

Answer (score -4):

Login with root user and execute the command:

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/file
```

OR

```
chmod -R 777 /path
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777