# PHP can't read file under 647

Tags: php

I'm just starting my studies on servers and file system in order to program a couple of utilities with PHP.

I have Apache set up as my local host at OS X. Just to make sure which user Apache is running as, I ran `posix_getpwuid(posix_getegid())['name']` and it returned the expected `_www`. Then I went ahead and ran

```
$filename = '/Volumes/HDD/programming/PHP/sandbox/dir_permissions_tests/text.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

At first I didn't want to create a separate group to add myself and Apache because I wanted to test how it would work if I added reading permission to "others". The output is also **"The file does not exist"**. Then I added reading permission to all directories in the file path as pointed out at [PHP can't read file with read permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846827/php-cant-read-file-with-read-permissions). Same problem. Then I added execution permissions as advised in the same link. No changes.

Am I wrong to presume that by having reading, writing and execution permissions set to all directories in the path and to the file itself for the "others" group PHP, by running under Apache `_www` should be able to find it regardless of the file and group it belongs to (that's why I'm trying under 647)? What am I missing? Maybe my understanding of "others" as "everything else" is not correct. I didn't intend to change ownership of all directories in the path just to make it work. Creating a separate group is an option, though, but I'd like to understand the issue with "others" first.

Many thanks.

Comment: Who owns the file being opened? Is it the Apache user, your user, some other user?

Comment: My user owns it. But my doubt is here too – in my understanding that shouldn’t be relevant as long as I’ve set all permissions to the “others” group.

Comment: add folder or file to apache .... chown -R apache:apache /path/to/your/folder/file

Comment: But by doing it recursively from the root I’ll change the ownership of my whole hard drive to Apache and that’s not what I want. Moreover, it still doesn’t answer the question: why the permissions set for “others” don’t work?

Comment: The "all" or "others" category refers to "any user which is not the owner user and/or owner group". This is why it's extremely dangerous to ever grant RWX to the `all` part of the world. It also means that "others" doesn't include you (as owner) nor Apache (if you make it part of the owning group).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I understand it. The issue is that Apache isn't part of the owning group. I've temporarily set RWX permissions to "others" exactly to test whether the file would be recognized as existent by PHP, but it hasn't. Matter of fact, I've even set 777 just to have it recognized (also as a test), but once I run the script nothing changes. Maybe something in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I changed the path from a root-relative to a document-relative one. Yet I would like some reference material to understand why root-relative ones don't work whereas in the function documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php a root-relative path is used in the examples.