# Issues with cURL connections - error setting certificate verify location

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, curl, nginx

We have been struggling with cURL since we've had our new server (no issues previously). In the last 6 months we've searched and tried to fix the issue at the root, with no success.

We are running an Ubuntu 16.04 server, with a Codeigniter project on PHP and Nginx.

The (composer) package we are currently having the issue with is the Mailgun API (which extends the composer package `php-http`)

Below is the error that we get when connecting via cURL

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Http\Client\Exception\RequestException

Message: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

Filename: /var/www/ domain /vendor/php-http/curl-client/src/Client.php

Line Number: 137
```

The only solution that has worked for us so far disabling `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, but we've had to do that inside the composer package, which obviously is not a proper solution.

I'm hoping someone here can please shed some light on how we might be able to resolve the issue.

What we have tried so far:

- Checked the date on the server
- Disable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, but not a viable solution
- Set `.curlrc` file (but issue is that webserver user is executing, so no place to put it?
- Checked the `/etc/ssl/certs/` folder to see if the files exist.
- `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh`

File permissions on the folder

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal /etc/ssl/certs # ls -la ca*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Apr 26 11:17 ca6e4ad9.0 -> ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 274340 Mar  8 17:09 ca-bundle.crt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 274340 Apr 26 11:25 ca-certificates.crt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 261889 Jan 18 06:12 cacert.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 261889 Jan 18 06:12 cacert.pem.txt
```

Comment: consider the [`curl.cainfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php#ini.curl.cainfo)

Comment: @Deadooshka Thanks, I have considered it, but not sure what you want me to do :-) I've checked it and it's set to `curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`. This file exists and have downloaded a new version from: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html.

Comment: did you check a file/directory permissions of that path?

Comment: it's a root's permissions, but the server/php may run with another user.

Comment: Yeah, but permissions are set to `rwxrwxrwx` (`777`)

Comment: can you read this file with ie `file_get_contents()` from the curl context?

Comment: Created a PHP file that I called from the browser: `Warning: file_get_contents(/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in`. But surely the file isn't read by PHP directly? The PHP curl lib is reading it. How would I tried to read the file from that context?

Comment: it's read by either php-interpreter or web-server process, unless you does run a curl executable. I would check also permissions of another directories of the path.

Comment: Just fixed the issue after reading this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6941351/690113. I had to execute `root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal /etc # chmod o+x ssl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have been struggling with this for a long time and haven't been able to find the answer anywhere, but found it due to the help of @ Deadooshka in a [not so related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6941351/690113), I'll leave my question and answer here.

For me the solution what that the `/etc/ssl` folder needed execute permission. I have no idea where this has gone wrong, but the solution for me was the following:

`$ /etc # chmod o+x ssl`

When the permissions were wrong, I could not read the certificate file using `file_get_contents(/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt)` in a PHP script in the web root, executed from the browser. After the fix, the file was read.